# Hiding files with incorrect extension

Tags: finder

When looking for a specific type of file from an application (for instance, looking for .ai files inside Adobe Illustrator), the finder makes all the files with the wrong extension not selectable. However, these files are still appearing in the list, even if faded. If you have a folder containing a a lot of files and only a few of the desired format, it can quickly become annoying to find them.

I would to know if there is a way to completely hide (not display at all) the undesired files?

Comment: This is something Adobe enabled. You cannot change the "Window-visibibly" by default for Adobe illustrator yourself

Comment: Well, Adobe Illustrator was just an example, I was wondering, if generally, it was possible to completely hide the files of the wrong type, like it is the case in windows.

Comment: I know in Finder you can type NOT .ai in the search-bar if you'd not like to see any Adobe Illustrator files. But that's not what you're looking for.

Comment: @Rob Well, not exactly. I was more looking for a magic command line make it happen system wide :)